# Regex using Java

Tags: java

I've tryied convert a snippet code from C# to Java but without success. My doubt is in `Regex` classes.

**C# code**

```
string estado = Regex.Match(pagina, "<td width=\"25\" style=\"padding: 2px\">(.*)</td>").Groups[1].Value;
estado = "<label>" + estado + "</label>";
```

In this code, I declare a string called `estado` and search in a another string called `pagina` a specific character.

How can I do this `Regex` in Java ?

**HTML (I simplify the sample because is too big, so I put three dots where don't means so much to me)**

```
<!DOCTYPE html SYSTEM "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd"> <html><head><meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"><title>Correios</title>
...
<td width="268" style="padding: 2px">Rua Satelite</td> 
<td width="140" style="padding: 2px">Caicara</td> 
<td width="140" style="padding: 2px">Belo Horizonte</td> 
<td width="25" style="padding: 2px">MG</td> 
<td width="65" style="padding: 2px">30280-291</td> 
</tr></table>
...
```

I need these `<td>` tags, but in Java Code.

Comment: string should be `String`

Comment: this is C# code, where `String` can be `string`

Comment: I note that you're parsing HTML with regex, which is [not ideal](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/244343).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Java does have regex. The regex capabilities are provided by the classes `Pattern` and `Matcher`. Your code would become:

```
String estado = Pattern.compile("<td width=\"25\" style=\"padding: 2px\">(.*)</td>").matcher(pagina).group();
estado = "<label>" + estado + "</label>";
```

For more info, see the package summary for [`java.util.regex`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/package-summary.html).

Comment: Without success, I got the `Exception: java.lang.IllegalStateException: No match found Message: java.lang.IllegalStateException: No match found` but I update my question where we can see that exist the `<td>` that I want